Installing Panasonic WhisperThin RG-T810LA in existing bathroom
So, I bought the Panasonic fan to replace an old Broan that was installed when my house was built 20 years ago.  The Panasonic has a vastly different footprint, so I went up in the rafters, exhumed the old fan box from under 2ft of blow-in insulation and removed it to make space, then cut the drywall to the size of the housing.
The hole has a rafter along one side, and I thought I could install the fan with the flange inside the bathroom and the body outside (as with others I've installed)|.  But with these thin fans, that's now how it works.  You're supposed to install it between the rafter and the drywall and use a bracket to go from one rafter to the other for stabilization, but in my case I can't get the flange into the space between the rafter and the drywall...because there isn't any.
My question: Can I just bend or cut the flange off on that side, and butt it up against the rafter with some caulk on it to ensure a good seal, or do I need to do something else?
FYI: instructions recommend caulk between flange and drywall to ensure proper seal.
At this point, the hole is 10.5"x10.5" (the size of the housing minus flange), one side runs along a rafter, and the other is several inches from the next rafter.
Any help would be appreciated.

it is not clear what is the problem ... please add pictures and/or a diagram

Pictures with captions. The flange you see is the one I'm considering bending or cutting. https://imgur.com/a/Qyg8phF

[Edit] your question, and use the built in image hosting to post your pic directly into the question. It can be missed down here.

Add a thin piece of wood to the rafter to allow the flange to sit on that edge.
Anchor it there.
You may need to modify the hole to fit the unit.
Use the mounting bar as directed. Spanning the rafters. ( it should not need to be bent.)

In your situation I would consider using an oscillating multitool to "gnaw" away at the bottom of the joist, or even the drywall.  You probably only need to trim 1/16" to slip the flange under.
